# Boolean Operator in Pandoc Template

Tags: pandoc

[Pandoc Template](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates) supports `if`-clauses and `for`-loops. For example,

```
$if(foo)$
part one
$else$
part two
$endif$
```

How to do boolean logic inside the `if`-clause argument? For example,

```
$if(foo AND bar)$
both
$endif$
```

and

```
$if(foo OR bar)$
both
$endif$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template language has no support for this. Boolean `AND` can be simulated by using two `if`s.

```
$-- foo AND bar
$if(foo)$
$if(bar)$
both
$endif$
$endif$
```

Boolean `OR` is not really possible though; the best method would be to use a partial to avoid too much repetition:

```
$-- foo OR bar
$if(foo)$
$my.partial()$
$else$
$if(bar)$
$my.partial()$
$endif$
$endif$
```

It is often easier to move the calculations to a (Lua) filter for even mildly complicated logic.

```lua
function Meta (meta)
  meta['foo-and-bar'] = meta.foo or meta.bar
  return meta
end
```

Drawback: if `foo` or `bar` are not part of the metadata but of the set of variables, then this won't work, as filters don't have access to variables. Use a custom writer in that case.